# Can I populate a table in MySQL without ending up with duplicated entries

Tags: mysql, database-design, duplicates, unique-key

I have a database. However whenever I am trying to add products to the cart table from a shopping page, I realize that the same item is added multiple times to the table if the add button for that item is so often clicked. Is there a way in which whenever a user clicks on the add button for a specific item, that if it was already added in the cart table, then it cannot be added again.

Comment: This strikes me more as a programming problem than a DBA one. Maybe you should ask it on stackoverflow? I think that it's off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Make your primary key (cart_id, product_id). If the user tries to add an existing product to a cart, then increment the quantity.

```
create table cart_items (
  cart_id int,
  product_id int,
  quantity int default 1,
  primary key (cart_id, product_id)
);

insert into cart_items (cart_id, product_id) values
(1,1)
on duplicate key update quantity = quantity + 1;

insert into cart_items (cart_id, product_id) values
(1,1)
on duplicate key update quantity = quantity + 1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da1ac/1

Answer (score 0):

What is the structure of the table you're adding products to? You could put a unique index on (userId, productId) column combination. That will prevent the same product from being added more times than once. You might want to check out [Insert... on duplicate key update](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax, though.